PySpark; Not being able to connect and read .json from MinIO
I have the problem that I cannot connect to MinIO using spark.
The MinIO endpoint is running on Kubernetes and I forwarded the ports, it is accessible using curl or mc, so the issue must lie somewhere within the spark code or the spark-submit command.
It fails in the line where the dataframe is defined.
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

def load_config(sc: SparkContext):
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", "minio")
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "minio123")
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "https://localhost:9000")
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true")
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "false")
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint.https.enabled", "true")
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint.https.disableSSLVerification", "true")

load_config(spark.sparkContext)

print("\n\n\n")

dataframe = spark.read.json('s3a://orders/orders.json')

average = dataframe.agg({'amount': 'avg'})

average.show()


spark-submit   --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.4,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bundle:1.12.262   test.py

The error looks always the same
24/12/31 00:48:35 INFO SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir.
24/12/31 00:48:35 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/home/master/minio-spark-jobs/spark-warehouse'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/master/minio-spark-jobs/test.py", line 20, in <module>
    dataframe = spark.read.json('s3a://orders/orders.json')
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 425, in json
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 179, in deco
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o34.json.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/impl/prefetch/PrefetchingStatistics
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1027)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:519)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3469)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:366)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:362)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:75)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:52)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.impl.prefetch.PrefetchingStatistics
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    ... 35 more

I really do not know how to fix this, I tried by adjusting the spark-submit command based on similar problems regarding the hadoopt and aws versions, which I saw on StackOverflow but it did not work.

From the error log, it might be caused by the class PrefetchingStatistics missed.
You can refer this answer, which is similar with your problem.
